# What is yield of a tea tree?

Tags: trees, harvesting, tea

I would like to plan plantation of tea. I would like to know how much tea a tea tree would yield. What is the quantity / frequency?

Comment: Where are you located, what cultivar are you going to use, and what shape is your soil in? How much care (irrigation, fertilization, pest/disease control) are you willing to give?

Comment: I don't know all that yet. I'm looking at average figures. I'll get he cultivars according to data, I'm planning to cultivate hydroponically and in controlled environment, with natural pest/disease control.

Comment: I need an overview before I can make decisions about particulars.

Comment: @J.Musser Although this question is for the purpose of large-scale agriculture, it is just about the yield of one tree. Is this on-topic?